# using jquery templates in a loop, need to prefill input items with ViewBag.values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-templates

I have a jquery template that I'm looping over x number of times to repeat  on a form.  When that form is reloaded, it automatically runs the loop to display all of the inputs according to what was previously selected, but I can't for the life of me wrap my head around how to put the values into those fields.

using something like this:

```
(string)ViewBag.myFieldValue{id}
```

doesn't work because it thinks it's a c# object (obviously).

how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A jquery template needs a json object to render. So you should put the values from your viewbag into a json object. Even better, a template can also receive a json array, and will render x number of templates depending on the number of objects in the array.

Take a look at this blogarticle and you will figure it out soon:

[An introduction to jquery templates](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates.aspx)